# Add Command on Existing Pop-up in Add-in

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, add-in

I have created an AddIn, in the past, in a different project. It creates a Pop-up "blah" that groups two sub-items, all under the Solution Explorer.

I am Creating a different AddIn, in a different project, and I would like to make it run under the same Pop-up folder.

How can I test if the pop-up with the name "blah", under the CommandBar type ["Project"], exists, and add a command inside the existing one if it does ? (if it doesn't, add the pop-up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to use the pop-up Caption.

There are two alternatives:

- use a Tag
- use an ID

Either way, I had to modify the existing Add-in to give it a Tag (and/or an ID), then

```
myPopup = (CommandBarPopup)proj.FindControl(Type: MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, Tag: "myTag");
if (myPopup == null)
{
  // create it
}
```